# How to use CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION in a user defined function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2017, change-tracking

I am working on a project that uses Entity Framework and change tracking in SQL Server. I want to create a user defined function that returns the current version of the tracked changes in the database, so that I can use it in my queries with Entity Framework.

However, when I try to create the function, I get the following error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'change_tracking_current_version' within a function.

Is there a way to create a user defined function with it without causing an error?

Here is the code of my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChangeVersion()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @version bigint;
SET @version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
RETURN @version;
END
```

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: [Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'change\_tracking\_min\_valid\_version' within a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117735/invalid-use-of-a-side-effecting-operator-change-tracking-min-valid-version-wit)

Comment: why do you need to create a function if you can just call it

Comment: @ThomA - Similar but `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` and `CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(table_object_id)` are not the same

Comment: Not the same function, sure, but the *reason* almost certainly is, @MartinSmith . They are both `CHANGE_TRACKING_<Describer>_VERSION` functions giving side-effecting errors, when they likely aren't (really).

Comment: But the difference is important. As `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION` is niladic that makes the view workaround more viable for this case

Comment: @siggemannen because I need it for Entity Framework and I do not know any other method how to map system function (I can map only user defined ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same workaround as also works for `RAND()`.

Create a helper view

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION
AS
SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() AS CurrentVersion
```

Then use

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChangeVersion()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @version bigint;
SET @version = (SELECT CurrentVersion FROM dbo.CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION)
RETURN @version;
END
```

Comment: This is not answer to 'why' but to 'how' but I have change the question to fit to the answer because it it in reality what I need to know.

Comment: Yeah I just answered the "Is there a way to create a user defined function with it without causing an error?" part. As I don't have access to the source code of builtin functions I can't answer "why"